# Connect to an empty subversion repository

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to connect to a repo of an URL that was given to me so that I can easily push files into it. I've first tried cloning it with "git clone {url}" but apparently it's a "Subversion rep." and those are handled differently. After a bit of googling, my understanding is that svn is an alternative to git, but one ought to be able to use svn through git by typing commands that start with "git svn".

I've managed to clone it but haven't managed to push anything. I work under windows, have git installed, don't have svn installed, and use git bash to type commands.

Here's the exact sequence of commands I've tried:

```
git svn clone <url>
git init
touch test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit test.txt
{wrote commit message}
git svn dcommit
```

At that point, I get the following message

> Migrating from a git-svn v1 layout...
>
> Data from a previous version of
>   git-svn exists, but
>
> .git/svn
>
> (required for this version (2.19.0.windows.1) of git-svn) does not exist.
>
> Done migrating from a git-svn v1 layout
>
> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.

Trying the command again, I just get "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history." If instead I try

```
git svn rebase
```

I get

> Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history

What do I do? Please assume zero competence with git on my part. I've already tried several online guides and, as usual, find them to be incomprehensible and therefore quite frustrating.

To clarify, this repo is currently empty. I just want to use it in the future. I don't need to import any existing files into it, and it's no issue if I have to clone it again. Also I'll be the only person using it, it's just for backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using [`git svn`](http://gitlab-tls), it would be simpler, for a subversion repository, to [use directly... subversion](https://www.codebasehq.com/blog/using-svn-in-windows).

That way, you are only dealing with Subversion rather than both Git and SVN, considering your remote repository is a Subversion one anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to install something else, but I now I did so anyway at your recommendation, and it worked immediately.